# How to format response before sending in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I followed the documentation and was able to add an interceptor for response mapping.

I want a consistent json format output for responses.

How can I achieve this with interceptor or with something else better than this approach.

```
{
  "statusCode": 201,
  "message": "Custom Dynamic Message"
  "data": {
     // properties
     meta: {}
  }
}
```

**transform.interceptor.ts**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Response<T> {
  statusCode: number;
  data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T>
  implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((data) => ({
          statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
          data,
        })),
      );
  }
}
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
export class AppController {
      @Post('login')
      @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
      @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Login user' })
      @ApiBody({ type: LoginDto })
      @ApiOkResponse({ content: { 'application/json': {} } })
      @UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
      async login(@Request() req) {
        const result = await this.authService.login(req.user);
        return { message: 'Thank you!', result };
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better than this approach"? Is there something about the Interceptor approach that you don't like?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel As I said earlier. How can I add a message key with a custom message in the json response? And what I meant was how can I achieve the desire result that I wanted using the interceptor approach. If we cannot achieve what I wanted using interceptor then is there any other approach for that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are doing with your controller response and your overall interceptor response, what you can do is something similar:

```js
import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Response<T> {
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
  data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T>
  implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((data) => ({
          statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
          message: data.message
          data: {
            result: data.result,
            meta: {} // if this is supposed to be the actual return then replace {} with data.result
          }
        })),
      );
  }
}
```

And keep your controller return as `{message: 'Custom message', result}`.

Another option, which would require more upfront but possible allow for cleaner code would be to create a custom decorator that reflected a value (message) from the class and method and then retrieved that value in the interceptor after injecting the reflector, but again, that would take more upfront effort to set up.

Comment: Thanks man this works but can you tell me more about the map function we are using here. Because earlier I tried to do something similar like your answer but I was not able to debug or print that iterator "data" in map function. Even when I put my breakpoint there it says undefined. Can you please help me on how to debug it?

Comment: `map` is the [rxjs operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map). What this does is it takes the observable returned from `next.handle()` which means the value returned from your controller (Nest makes in an observable automatically so you shouldn't need to worry about that), then it should take `data` and map it accordingly to our new format using that arrow function that returns a json. If you'd like to `console.log(data)` you'll need to change it from immediately returning a json to using the word `return` and only using `{}`, not `({})`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of requiring every controller to always include a message property in the response data, I utilized reflectors and `SetMetadata` to extract the message value and set it as metadata on the controller method.

*response_message.decorator.ts*

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const ResponseMessage = (message: string) =>
      SetMetadata('response_message', message);
```

*response.interceptor.ts*

```
import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Response<T> {
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
  data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T>
  implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>>
{
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data) => ({
        statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
        message:
          this.reflector.get<string>(
            'response_message',
            context.getHandler(),
          ) || '',
        data,
      })),
    );
  }
}
```

usage in controller

*media.controller.ts*

```
 @Get('/stats')
  @ResponseMessage('Fetched Stats Succesfully')
  getUserMediaStats(@GetUser('id') userId: Types.ObjectId) {
    return this.mediaService.getUserMediaStats(userId);
  }
```

My Response Structure

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Fetched Stats Succesfully",
    "data": {
        "userId": "6419cbb6c053f0692ef400ae",
        "totalCount": 8,
        "totalSizeMB": 2.079585,
        "imageCount": 8,
        "videoCount": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the above two answers

src\interceptors\transform.interceptor.ts

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

export interface Response<T> {
 statusCode: number;
 message: string;
 data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformationInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, 
Response<T>> {
constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): 
Observable<Response<T>> {
   return next.handle().pipe(
   map((data) => ({
    message: this.reflector.get<string>('response_message', 
      context.getHandler()) || data.message || '',
    statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
    data: data.result || data
   }))
   );
 }
}
```

src\employees\employees.controller.ts

```
@Get()
@ResponseMessage('Employees records fetched Succesfully')
findAll() {
  return this.employeesService.findAll();
}
```

Response structure

```
 {
   "message": "Employees records fetched Succesfully",
   "statusCode": 200,
   "data": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "code": "2001",
       "companyCode": "01",
       "firstName": "Walter",
       "lastName": "Mendoza",
       "email": "w.dummy@gmail.com",
       "phone": "+1214",
       "siteId": 4,
       "roleId": 5,
       "isActive": 0,
       "inviteStatus": 3,
       "shiftId": null,
       "createdAt": "2019-08-26T15:21:44.000Z",
       "syncAt": "2022-10-09T19:01:40.000Z",
       "modifiedAt": "2022-10-09T19:01:40.000Z"
     },
     {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "2002",
      "companyCode": "01",
      "firstName": "Hugo",
      "lastName": "Rosa",
      "email": "dummy@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+18324888233",
      "siteId": 4,
      "roleId": 5,
      "isActive": 1,
      "inviteStatus": 3,
      "shiftId": null,
      "createdAt": "2019-08-26T15:21:44.000Z",
      "syncAt": "2022-10-09T19:01:40.000Z",
      "modifiedAt": "2022-10-09T19:01:40.000Z"
     }
    ] 
   }



 @Get(':id')
 async findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
     const result = await this.employeesService.findOne(+id);
     return { message: `Employees ${id} detail fetched Succesfully`, 
     result};
 }
```

Response Structure

```
{
 "message": "Employees 1 detail fetched Succesfully",
 "statusCode": 200,
 "data": {
  "id": 1,
  "code": "2001",
  "companyCode": "01",
  "firstName": "Walter",
  "lastName": "Mendoza",
  "email": "dummy@gmail.com",
  "phone": "+1214",
  "siteId": 4,
  "roleId": 5,
  "isActive": 0,
  "inviteStatus": 3,
  "shiftId": null,
  "createdAt": "2019-08-26T15:21:44.000Z",
  "syncAt": "2022-10-09T19:01:40.000Z",
  "modifiedAt": "2022-10-09T19:01:40.000Z"
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).